# \thispagestyle{empty} and page numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, page-numbering

I'm trying to suppress the page number on a few pages of a large document. I'm using `\thispagestyle{empty}` to perform this task, and it works exactly as I want it to. However, when I later compile the document, the page numbers are wrong in my Table of Contents. I have determined that it is the above command that is throwing off the TOC. How can I suppress a page number, but have the TOC count it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: `\thispagestyle{empty}` doesn't suppress advancing the page number.

Comment: You have to run LaTeX twice to get the table of contents updated correctly.

Comment: That was, indeed, the problem. Compiling twice fixed the issue. Thanks.

Comment: 'Too localized' on that basis.